# C# : How to design a UI that couples to a dynamically generated object?

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection, dll

I have an issue with the software I am developing at work. I am creating a dll file after the user does the following steps.

1. Specify certain parameters and computation code into a win form.
2. Specify name of the dll.

Once this is done, I create all the necessary code files (using codeDOM) and compile the source files to generate the dll.

Now, my problem is with the UI. I want to present parameters within the objects of the dll in my UI, but I do not know what parameters the user is going to add.

I want a system where I can maybe specify configuration files to couple the UI elements (which i know in advance) and the objects within the dll (which i have no prior knowledge of, except for the information i can glean off from using Reflection).

So, in effect, I want to bring the coupling between UI elements (label.text, etc) outside of my code and into, maybe an xml file, and my UI should use this xml file to populate data from objects within the dynamically loaded dll.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why dont you use Key Value Pairs? Tuple? or Dictionary?

Comment: You've kinda answered your own question. Use reflection to look for the method name defined in your XML file.. and bind the results to the control name in your text file.. ?

Comment: @DarthVader : Shouldn't the key value pairs be coded in the program. Here, the user might generate a new dll at a later point of time. In such a case, he must be able to just modify the xml configuration file for the UI and then the program must run as it is i.e no recompilation is required.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead : Can you give me an example. I'm new to using reflection. Do you want me to code the 'search and fill' part in the UI and then populate it's 'search' parameters from the XML file?? Is that what you mean? I have considered it, but wouldn't it make the progam slow??

Comment: The idea is to have two programs. One is the admin program that generates the dlls.( I will be the person generating the dlls ). The users will have a client program and will add functionality to their programs by requesting dlls from me.

Comment: Could you use something like a custom attribute to decorate the dll being generated, then reflection can just home into those? You can then use params on the attributes for additional context

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short code snippet to get you started:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom("generated_asm.dll");
// or if the assembly is already loaded:
// asm = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().First(a => a.GetName().Name == "Generated.Assembly");

var type = asm.GetType("InsertNamespaceHere.InsertTypeNameHere");

// creates a table layout which you can add to a form (preferable you use the designer to create this)
var tbl = new TableLayoutPanel { ColumnCount = 2 };

// enumerate the public properties of the type
foreach(var property in type.GetProperties())
{
  tbl.Add(new Label(property.Name));

  var input = new TextBox { Tag = property };
  input.TextChanged = this.HandleTextChanged;
  input.Enabled = property.CanWrite;

  tbl.Add(input);
}
```

and in the handler you could use this:

```
void HandleTextChanged(object source, ...) {
  var input = source as TextBox;
  var property = input.Tag as PropertyInfo;
  property.GetSetMethod().Invoke(this.instanceOfThatType, new object[] { Convert.ChangeType(input.Text, property.PropertyType) });
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to look at [Prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc785479.aspx) or [MEF (Managed Extensibility Framework)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx).  There's definitely support for the kind of late binding that you're describing. In fact, this is the technology stack we use at work to shimmy in the assemblies for late-binding (more or less like a plug-in architecture).